# Find $f(x)$ which is the equation of a cylinder.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

A cylinder which equation is $y=f(x)$ is tangent to the surface $z^2+2xz+y=0$ in every point such that are in both surfaces.

I need to find $f(x)$, and I'm not sure how to get it. Only thing I'm able to do is to get the tangent plane to the surface. I also thought about the implicit function theorem, but I don't have an exact point to apply it. Any hits?

Comment: What definition of "cylinder" do you have in mind?

Comment: There are many types of cylinders, the exercise doesn't specify.

Comment: You have two surfaces: one given by $y=f(x)$ and one given by $z^2+2xz+y=0$. If you know how to get the tangent plane for a surface given by an equation, can you find that for each surface? Then you can write down what it means for the tangent planes to be the same at a point, which could help you figure out when the first surface is tangent to the second.